# How to get a sub-process' return code

Tags: c++, winapi

What is the method of getting the return value from spawning a sub-process within windows?  It looks like `ShellExecute()` is simpler to use than is `CreateProcess()`, but from the reading I've done thus far, neither indicate how to check the return value of the spawned process.  How is that done?

Thanks,
Andy

Answer (score 25, accepted):

To acquire the exit code of a process on Windows you can use [`GetExitCodeProcess()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683189%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Example application that accepts the process id as an argument and waits for five seconds for it to complete and then acquires its exit code:

```
int main(int a_argc, char** a_argv)
{
    int pid = atoi(*(a_argv + 1));

    HANDLE h = OpenProcess(SYNCHRONIZE | PROCESS_QUERY_INFORMATION, FALSE, pid);

    if (NULL != h)
    {
        WaitForSingleObject(h, 5000); // Change to 'INFINITE' wait if req'd
        DWORD exit_code;
        if (FALSE == GetExitCodeProcess(h, &exit_code))
        {
            std::cerr << "GetExitCodeProcess() failure: " <<
                GetLastError() << "\n";
        }
        else if (STILL_ACTIVE == exit_code)
        {
            std::cout << "Still running\n";
        }
        else
        {
            std::cout << "exit code=" << exit_code << "\n";
        }
        CloseHandle(h);
    }
    else
    {
        std::cerr << "OpenProcess() failure: " << GetLastError() << "\n";
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you.  This is what I was looking for.  Looks like I'll have to use CreateProcess() to start this thing.  That function fills a PROCESS_INFORMATION structure that has the HANDLE I need for use with GetExitCodeProcess().

Comment: When you are finished with the handle, be sure to close it using the `CloseHandle` function.

Answer (score 9):

Here is a complete code based in http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682512%28v=vs.85%29.aspx and the solution of hmjd:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <Windows.h>

int main()
{
  const size_t stringSize = 1000;
  STARTUPINFO si;
  PROCESS_INFORMATION pi;
  DWORD exit_code;
  char commandLine[stringSize] = "C:\\myDir\\someExecutable.exe param1 param2";
  WCHAR wCommandLine[stringSize];
  mbstowcs (wCommandLine, commandLine, stringSize);

  ZeroMemory( &si, sizeof(si) );
  si.cb = sizeof(si);
  ZeroMemory( &pi, sizeof(pi) );

  // Start the child process. 
  if( !CreateProcess( NULL,   // No module name (use command line)
      wCommandLine,   // Command line
      NULL,           // Process handle not inheritable
      NULL,           // Thread handle not inheritable
      FALSE,          // Set handle inheritance to FALSE
      0,              // No creation flags
      NULL,           // Use parent's environment block
      NULL,           // Use parent's starting directory 
      &si,            // Pointer to STARTUPINFO structure
      &pi )           // Pointer to PROCESS_INFORMATION structure
  ) 
  {
      printf("CreateProcess failed (%d).\n", GetLastError() );
      return -1;
  }

  // Wait until child process exits.
  WaitForSingleObject( pi.hProcess, INFINITE );

  GetExitCodeProcess(pi.hProcess, &exit_code);

  printf("the execution of: \"%s\"\nreturns: %d\n", commandLine, exit_code);

  // Close process and thread handles. 
  CloseHandle( pi.hProcess );
  CloseHandle( pi.hThread );
  return 0;
}
```

(runs as VS2005 console application in windows XP)

Comment: It would be prudent to add quotes around 0th command-line parameters in case someone copies the snippet puts `...\my dir\...` in there.

Comment: It works well as is (it is proven). No additional quotes needed, even if the path contains spaces. Conversely, if the quotes around "commandLine" are added, "CreateProcess" will not work.